# so conceived after comma

Tags: commas

Naturalism, on this understanding, is the view that there is nothing outside the natural world, so conceived.

What does "so conceived" mean exactly here?

Comment: It means “in the sense the term is defined/used here”.

Comment: Thanks! But it is about "being outside the natural world" or about "natural world"?

Comment: I suppose you could say that.

Comment: It's more natural to consider it to reference just "the natural world".